# C++ subtracting functions form each other

Tags: c++

I need to figure out how to subtract the values of two functions from each other, basically using the method below to make this work within my main method. In the main method i take the character from the user, and the amount of messageUnits from the user and then apply it into the calculationA function. I want to subtract one of the functions values from another one of its calculated values.

```
cout << "Cost savings $" << calculationA('a', units) - calculationA('b', units) << endl;



double calculationA(char a, double messageUnits)
{
    if (a == 'a' || 'A')
    {
        const double constantA = 10.95;
        if (messageUnits > 10)
        {
            double cost = ((messageUnits - 10) * 0.50 + (constantA));
            return cost;
        }
        else if (messageUnits <= 10)
        {
            return constantA;
        }
    }
    else if (a == 'b' || 'B')
    {
        const double constantB = 19.95;
        if (messageUnits > 20)
        {
            double cost = ((messageUnits - 20) * 0.25 + (constantB));
            return cost;
        }
        else if (messageUnits <= 20)
        {
            return constantB;
        }
    }
    else if (a == 'c' || 'C')
    {
        const double constantC = 39.95;
        return constantC;
    }
    else
    {
        //note for myself during debugging
        cout << "Ooops! Something went wrong! " << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Side note: using names like `constantA` and `constantB` doesn't make your code any clearer than if you just wrote `10.95` and `19.95`.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: http://ideone.com/EguW4S

Comment: I cant subtract two of the functions calculations from each other, look at the first line of code that outputs cost savings: dont pay too much attention to it's placement, it actually lies within my main method.

Comment: Please explain what results you get and what you expected.

Comment: When in doubt, assign return values from functions to variables.  Let the compiler worry about optimizing your program.

Comment: I know this is not your question, but besides the problem pointed out by Scott Hunter in his answer, you might want to avoid future bugs by removing the `if(...)` parts from the `else` branches of your inner if statements (i.e. just `else` instead of `else if`). The two cases you detect in each of them are logical negations of each other anyways, so no need for another `if` (as long as you don't add a third case, like in the outer `if` statement). In your version you'd always have to remember to change the numbers in two places.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` conditions should be of the form `(a=='b')||(a=='B')` instead of `a=='b'||'B'`.

Comment: Addendum: Enabling full warning should enable the compiler to warn about that bug.

Comment: Thanks i changed, the values of the if conditions to what the correction posted above. Why would a == 'b' || 'B' be incorrect? Just curious.

Comment: Your `if` conditions should be of the form `if (a==std::toupper('B'))` instead of `(a=='b')||(a=='B')`.

Comment: `a == 'b' || 'B'` will be always evaluate to true since `B` is non-zero.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I suspect you meant `if (std::toupper(a) == 'B')`.

Comment: `a=='b'||'B'` is interpreted as `(a=='b')||'B'`; as RSahu says, this will be considered true regardless of what is in `a` because `'B'` is non-zero (0 is interpreted as false, everything else as true).  That's just how the compiler works.